# Vue3 component not binding

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Changing the values inside my component are not updating the parent values for some reason.

If I replace the Vuetify components with standard `<input>` it works fine. Don't see anything in the Vuetify docs that say I should be doing something different.

MyComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <v-radio-group inline :label="title" :model-value="selectionValue"
        @update:selectionValue="$emit('update:selectionValue', $event.target.value)">
        <v-radio label="Yes" :value=true />
        <v-radio label="No" :value=false />
    </v-radio-group>
    <div v-if="!selectionValue">
        <v-textarea :label="reasonTitle" :model-value="reasonValue"
            @update:reasonValue="$emit('update:reasonValue', $event.target.value)" density="compact" rows="3" />

    </div>
</template>
  
<script setup>
import { defineProps, defineEmits } from 'vue'

defineProps({
    title: String,
    selectionValue: Boolean,
    reasonTitle: String,
    reasonValue: String
})

defineEmits(['update:selectionValue', 'update:reasonValue'])

</script>
```

Parent.vue

```
<template>
<MyComponent title="Are you sure?" reasonTitle="Why?"
    v-model:selectionValue="selectedValue" v-model:reasonValue="reasonText" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.vue'

const selectedValue = ref(false);
const reasonText = ref("parent default");

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuetify components are not guaranteed to emit all the same events as similar native HTML elements. Always check the API documentation.

For both [v-radio-group](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-radio-group/#events) and [v-textarea](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-textarea/#events) you will want to listen for the `update:modelValue` event.  Because these components can only ever have a single v-model, these event names don't change based on the "modelValue" name in your parent component. It's when you re-emit to the parent where the modelValue name matters.

```html
<v-radio-group
  :model-value="selectionValue"
  @update:modelValue="$emit('update:selectionValue', $event)"
>
```

```html
<v-textarea
  :model-value="reasonValue"
  @update:modelValue="$emit('update:reasonValue', $event)"
/>
```

Also notice that you need to emit `$event`, not  `$event.target.value` like you would with a native HTML element. Vuetify is providing the value of the component for you as the entire `$event`

[Vuetify Playground example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: I'm new to Vue (painfully obvious I know) and just trying to get some of this stuff to click. How you present it makes a lot of sense. I tried every combination I could and was so close. Thanks again for the help and enjoy your fake internet points :D